# Only Button-1 Works in Event Bind Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas.pack()

one = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 500, 500, fill = 'red')
two = canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 500, 500, fill = 'green')



def move_rectangle(canvas, one):
    canvas.move(one, 2, 3)
    canvas.move(two,4,5)

def callback(event):
    move_rectangle(canvas, one)
    move_rectangle(canvas, two)


canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

mainloop()
```

If I change Button-1 to anything else, nothing happens. Right now two different rectangles will  move across the screen. I am trying to set up a bind for rectangle one and a different key bind for rectangle two. However I can't even seem to bind to anything other than Button-1. If I change Button-1 to Button-2 nothing happens, I have also tried Return and arrow keys with no luck.

Comment: From your description, I'm not sure you get the fact that changing it to `<Button-2>` means you want to get right-mouse-button clicks instead of left-mouse-button clicks, so before anything else… you understand that, and the problem is that binding `<Button-2>` doesn't get right-button clicks like you expected, right?

Comment: Anyway, what platform (including full OS version, and 32 or 64 bit if Windows), which Python version (and 32 or 64 bit if Windows), and Tk version (if on Mac or Linux and you installed Tk manually)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `<Button-1>` to `<Button-2>` in your code, the right mouse button should just work. There may be some weird platform-/version-specific oddities, but without knowing anything about your system, I can't comment.

But changing it to, e.g., `<Left>` is *not* going to work. Only the window with keyboard focus gets keyboard events. And since you don't have any text-entry-type auto-focusing widgets, and aren't doing anything to explicitly set focus, that's your `root`.

So, there are two fixes. Either one will work, and in your particular case (where a `Canvas` owns the entire root and there are no other widgets anywhere), I don't think there's going to be much difference between them.

1. Call `canvas.focus_set` right before `mainloop`.
2. Call `root.bind` instead of `canvas.bind`.

One more thing to watch out for: On many *nix systems, when you run a Tkinter script from the terminal, it doesn't actually jump to the foreground. So, it won't receive keyboard input until you click somewhere on the window.

Comment: I think the sticking point here is that the right mouse button is `<Button-3>`, while the middle/wheel button is `<Button-2>`.

Comment: I had the same problem and using `root.bind` works beautifully for me. Thanks!